# MongoDB connection gradually increase. How to resolve this problem?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm currently using mongoDB in my development server. Using PHP 1.1.4 driver and connecting to mongoDB with persist command.

But somehow my db connection number is gradually increasing but never seems to end those connections perhaps no timeout?

I'm worried that if I deploy my source, it might cause some problem that full of connection pool won't let people to use mongoDB at all.

How can I set timeout shorter or somehow resolve gradually increasing connection problem though there is only one user.

Comment: What's the maxConns setting in your mongo config file?

Comment: I did not manually config anything. I'm probably using default setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of your running code uses its own pool of persistant connections.
Are the operations assigned to each connection getting finished fast ? There might be slow queries in your code. Do share the snapshot of `mongostat` from your running instance. That would help. It `mongostat` shows everything is fine, then it might be PHP mongodb driver bug.

See :

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/ac005be798b6adea?pli=1

What I would suggest is, use non-persistant connections and explicitly close them at the end of your script.
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.close.php

Though there  is a little performance hit as persistant connections are better, but that can be ignored for moderate traffic.

Comment: Good answer but I do not share your idea when you say explicitly close the connection at the end of a script. According've been reading, it is not recommended to close the connection under normal circumstances. See : http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.close.php

Comment: @evolquez Yes , I agree, the connection pooling must be best left to the driver.
The solution suggested by me was a way to overcome a bug present in PHP driver at that time